# How to make an old version Merant PVCS work in Windows 7?

Tags: windows-7, pvcs

I am trying to make an old version of Merant PVCS function in Windows 7.  The version my company has installed is: 8.0.2.3 Build 662

The application installs ok, but it does not open.  It basically just blinks on the screen and goes away without any kind of error messaging.

Running in XP compatibilty mode is also not an option as my company has disabled that feature.

I found a support article about it: http://communities.serena.com/serena/topics/pvcs_vm_8_2_1_does_not_run_on_windows_7-1d2sbp

but the link to the actual fix appears to be missing or dead.

Any help would be swell!

Comment: There are [one](http://sourceforge.net/projects/pvcspluginproj/) or [two](http://sourceforge.net/projects/pvcscommander/) Eclipse plugins for PVCS integration as well as a plugin for [Jenkins](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/PVCS+SCM).

Comment: [Archive of previous discussion](https://web.archive.org/web/20141203150131/http://communities.serena.com/serena/topics/pvcs_vm_8_2_1_does_not_run_on_windows_7-1d2sbp)